# How find the minimum point on the plotted line (xmin, ymin) add the minimum point?

Tags: python, plot, visualization, min

i can't find min. How to add minimum point? Please help
How find the minimum point on the plotted line (xmin, ymin) add the minimum point ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = x*x - 2*x + 23

# Plot
plt.plot(x, y)

# Plot title
plt.title("\nQuadratic Function: y=x*x - 5*x + 23\n", fontsize=16, weight="bold", color = "red")


# Axis Labels
plt.xlabel("X", fontsize = 10, weight="bold", color="red")
plt.ylabel("Y", fontsize = 10, weight="bold", color="red")

# Add minimum point: To Do 


# Grid
plt.grid()

# Display plot
plt.show()
```

How to fix the code to work?

```
a = (y[np.argmin(y)])
b = (x[np.argmin(x)])
print(a,b)
plt.scatter(a, b, color="lightgreen", s=25)
```

Comment: `a = x[np.argmin(y)]` and `b = y[np.argmin(y)]` and also in your title it should be `y = x*x - 2*x + 23`

Comment: Hello and welcome to the stack overflow community. If the answer solved your question it would be nice if you could accept (check mark button) or upvote so that other users see that this problem was solved and the author earns some reputation for his work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up your coordinates for the function's minimum. You want to have minimum y value but the corresponding x value for that y. This corresonding x value is calculated by `a = x[y.argmin()]`. See code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = x*x - 2*x + 23

# Plot
plt.plot(x, y)

# Plot title
plt.title("\nQuadratic Function: y=x*x - 5*x + 23\n", fontsize=16, weight="bold", color = "red")


# Axis Labels
plt.xlabel("X", fontsize = 10, weight="bold", color="red")
plt.ylabel("Y", fontsize = 10, weight="bold", color="red")

plt.grid()

a = x[y.argmin()]
b = y.min()
plt.scatter(a, b, color="lightgreen", s=25)
```

[image]